# How do i prove this property of Riemann-integrable function?

Tags: real-analysis, integration, analysis, limits

Let $f$ be a Riemann-integrable function.

That is, it's upper sum and lower sum are the same.

Then, how do i prove that $\int_a^b f dx = \lim_{n\to\infty} \sum_{i=1}^n f(a+\frac{b-a}{n}i)\frac{b-a}{n}$?

More generally, let $S_n$ be a partition of $[a,b]$ which cosists of subintervals with legnth $\frac{b-a}{n}$. Then for any partition $P$, does there exist $S_n$ such that $L(P,f)≦L(S_n,f)$?

Comment: L denotes the lower sum

Answer (score 1):

$ \sum_{i=1}^n f(a+\frac{b-a}{n}i)\frac{b-a}{n}$ is comprised between $S(S_{n}, f)$ and $s(S_{n},f)$, i.e we have $$s(S_{n},f) \leq  \sum_{i=1}^n f(a+\frac{b-a}{n}i)\frac{b-a}{n} \leq S(S_{n}, f)$$ but if $ n \rightarrow \infty $ then $S(S_{n}, f)$ and $s(S_{n},f)$ tend to $\int_{a}^{b}f(x)dx$ because$f$ is Riemann integrable.

So $\int_{a}^{b}f(x)dx = \lim_{n\to\infty} \sum_{i=1}^n f(a+\frac{b-a}{n}i)\frac{b-a}{n}$

Note: $s(S_{n},f)$ and $S(S_{n},f)$ are the inferior and superior Riemann sums.

Comment: You assumed the question i asked. What i asked was whether $\lim_{n\to\infty} S(S_n,f)$ converges to $\int_a^b f dx$.

Comment: $\int_a^b f dx$ is evaluated by taking infimum of all $S(P,f)$ for partitions $P$. Hence it is $\int_a^b f dx ≦ \lim_{n\to\infty} S(S_n,f)$. I'm asking the converse

Comment: My question holds true when it is continuous or monotonic. Although it seems likely to hold generally, i failed to prove whenever i try to prove this..(I tried this last year too) Please help.

Comment: @John. p: I think that if $P$ is a partition such that $S(P,f ) \leq \int f + \epsilon $ then for $n$ sufficiently large $S_{n}$ is finer than $P$, and so $ \int f \leq S(S_{n}, f ) \leq S(P,f ) \leq \int f + \epsilon $

Comment: @John. p: for the inferior sums is analogous

Comment: I believe so too! But whenever i tried to prove it i failed. For example, let $P=\{0,\pi,5\}$ be a partition of $[0,5]$. Then, for any n. Then some subintervals induced by $P$ may have smaller sum than corresponding subinterval of $S_n$ while others may have greater sum. Moreover, let's assume that $\forall \epsilon>0, \exists n\in\mathbb{Z}^+$ such that $S(S_n,f)-s(S_n,f)<\epsilon$. This is even not sufficient to prove whether they have limit or not.

Comment: @John.p: I 've found this, try to look http://nvlpubs.nist.gov/nistpubs/jres/47/jresv47n3p191_A1b.pdf